# inconsistencies with imagesc for matlab => illustrator

Tags: matlab, adobe-illustrator

This is a reoccurring problem that I have with Matlab and Illustrator (2018 CC):

`imagesc` of a lot of data looks ever so slighly different if pasted in illustrator. This seems dangerous in a scientific context and seems hard to understand from a strictly end-user perspective.

1. Can someone explain from a technical point of view how this could (or is) happening?
2. Is there a way to create dense `imagesc`'s, in a vectorized form (without the distortion of data)?

Code to reproduce the described issue, screenshots below detailing some visible issues:

```
rng default %for reproducability, ver: Matlab2020b
data=smoothdata(rand([2000 40])-.5,2,"movmean",10); %some representative example data
[~,idx]=sort(mean(data(:,20:25),2));
figure; imagesc(data(idx,:));
caxis([-.35 .35]);
ylim([1979 2001])
```

[image]

legend: `imagesc` copied into in Illustrator (CMYK) file:

- A: copy figure with `print('-clipboard','-dmeta')` option in matlab (after `ylim([1980 2000])`)
- B: copy figure by screengrab (after `ylim([1980 2000])`)
- C: figure with issues: full y-scale figure: `ylim([0 2000])`, copied with `print('-clipboard','-dmeta')` to Illustrator, then manually zoomed in. The 'macroscopic view' doesn't seem to reflect the actual data very well (e.g. line 1984 is duplicated in the zoom-in)

Comment: My guess is that the copy to clipboard function copies the contents of the screen (and will be affected by your screen resolution).  Do you get the same output if you save the figure with 300DPI or higher (using Export and set the renderer to Raster with a high DPI)?

Comment: @lent2: you mean it's not really vectorized anyway?

Comment: That's my guess, I think the default behaviour for imagesc is to draw a canvas rather than keeping the data vectorized.  The resolution of this canvas is probably limited by your screen (maybe there is another setting/option to change it), I'll post a workaround bellow

Comment: Use this to export your figure to a raster format for importing elsewhere: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export_fig .This will produce much better results than the solution in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Since `imagesc` seems to draw a single canvas, another solution is to use `pcolor` which draws one patch per pixel:

```
rng default %for reproducability, ver: Matlab2020b
data=smoothdata(rand([2000 40])-.5,2,"movmean",10); %some representative example data
[~,idx]=sort(mean(data(:,20:25),2));
figure;
h = pcolor(data(idx,:));
set(h, 'EdgeColor', 'none');
caxis([-.35 .35]);
% ylim([1979 2001])
```

This takes a lot more memory and on my little laptop it took a couple of minutes to copy into Inkscape (I don't have illustrator installed).

Alternatively, it might be possible to use the `'-r300'` option to `print` to change the patch resolution.  I think the manual says the default is `'-r150'`.

### Edit

Using the following code to generate a comparison between `imagesc` and `pcolor`

```
figure;
subplot(1, 2, 1);
h = pcolor(data(idx,:));
set(h, 'EdgeColor', 'none');
title('pcolor');
caxis([-.35 .35]);
set(gca(), 'layer', 'top')
% ylim([1979 2001])

subplot(1, 2, 2);
imagesc(data(idx,:));
title('imagesc');
set(gca(), 'YDir', 'normal');
```

Produces the following image (not what I expected either):

[image: comparison between pcolor and imagesc]

Comment: wow, the pcolor plot looks completely different in my hands... I can't very well post pictures in the comment, but if you add the pcolor and the imagesc side by side they look scarily different :-O how is this even a thing

Comment: There is downsampling of the figure here, which will look different for Easter graphics with antialiasing enabled and for raster graphics. Neither is “correct”, since neither shows all the data.